# How to disable superview touchBegan event

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UIView subclass, all it has to do is:

```
@implement MyView
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"touch began");
}
@end
```

Now I create two MyView instances, one(C) is 50px height, the other one(S) is 100px height. The shorter one(C) is the subview of the taller one(S), they have diffrent background color.

Then I run the App, and click on the C, both C and S receive touchesBegan event.

My questionis, how do I prevent S(the superview) from receiving touch event when I tap on C? While C is above it(if C is an instance of UIButton, it works as expected).

For the image below:

- when I tap on the red view, both blue view and red view receive event, but I want only the red view receive it.
- when I tap on the blue area, only the blue view receive event, it works as expected.

[image]

**----edited 1----**

This method works only if I only use MyView, it does not prevent event propagation:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if(touch.view != self){
        // ignore the event
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"touch began");
}
```

**----edited 2----**

see @TomasCamin's comment

Comment: Is there any method like we do with javascript in a web browser, with javascript, it is `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: actually it's `event.stopPropagation()` in browser. preventDefault does more than stopPropagation.

Comment: I just tried to replicate your issue on iOS 8.1 but failed to do so. Touches on C are not propagated to S, unless I call  `[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];` in `MyView`'s `touchesBegan:touches`

Comment: @TomasCamin my mistake, I lost the call to `[super touchesBegan]` in the code snipet, maybe I should test touch.view to determine whethere `[super touchesBegan]` should be called or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
//your (S) view code
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
  if (CGRectContainsPoint(yourCView.frame,location))
    return;
}
```

Comment: It simply doesn't work. You must notice that, the two views are overlapped.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [UIView.exclusiveTouch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/exclusiveTouch)?

**Edit**: Ok, as I've read about `UIView.exclusiveTouch` it only disables touches on other views outside view's frame after user started touch on given view.

Try to override [pointInside:withEvent:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/pointInside:withEvent:) to return `No` if point is inside subview. Then `touchesBegan:withEvent:` shouldn't be triggered if you return `No`.

**Edit 2**: nevermind, this won't work too, because it will block subviews from receiving touches too. Probably you really should call super only if hit is outside subview:

```
if (self.subviews.count != 0) { // some naive implementation
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
NSLog(@"touch began");
```

Alternatively you can describe actual problem you trying to solve, maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Tried, both parent and subview getting the event when `self.exclusiveTouch = YES;`

Comment: Thanks for your patient attention. I want to build a custom UIView, that will deal with Tap event(not using UIGuestureRecognizers), once the subview has handled the event, it should prevent its superview from handling it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use different tag each of view, then you can check which view is touched using tag.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
  UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 100)];
myView.tag = 100;
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

}

```
   -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *toucheObject = [touches anyObject];
if (toucheObject.view.tag == 100) {
    // your code
    NSLog("Your Object Touche");
}
```

}

Comment: It worked, but I need a common solution. Because many times we are not able to set tag for every view.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably calling `[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];` inside the `[MyView touchBegan:withEvent]` as I wasn't able to replicate the problem you're reporting.

If it suits your needs I would rather use a [`UIGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/touchesBegan:withEvent:).

For example if you're trying to intercept just a tap use the `UITapGestureRecognizer` subclass:

```
@implementation View

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)tapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    NSLog(@"MyView tapped %p", self);
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, I was calling `[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];` but I got to miss it in my question, now I added it up.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is delete the

```
 [super touches began:....]
```

//and probably from the other 3 touch events - moved: ended: cancelled:

And you'll get what you want. The default implementation (which you are invoking by passing the event up to your superclass) is what is causing the event to continue up the responder chain (to the superview)